# Wix web application repair

Tags: iis, web-applications, installation, wix

For a windows application installer..i can do repair(rather than uninstall and then install) My question is.. after install a web application by wix installer, it can be on IIS manager.
Can i repair that web application by wix installer(to avoid uninstall and install again)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the IIS standard custom custom actions with the WiX toolset (like all standard custom actions provided with the WiX toolset) support repair as well as install, uninstall, patch, rollback for all those.